# Keep image height and hide its overflow part when it is wider than its container

Tags: css

I have the following code:

```
<div class="image-container">
   <img src="myimage.jpg">
</div>

img {
    height: 400px;
}
```

The size of the image is 800px X 400px. On desktop, the image can be displayed in full. When I reduce the browser width and make the viewport smaller than 800px in width, the image's height is kept, but it's compressed horizontally, resulting in a distorted image. How can I add CSS to the image or its container to hide its overflow part so that I can see a clipped image without distortion? Hopefully the image is always centered in the container.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to scale the image down so that it is contained within the viewport (while still maintaining its aspect ratio)? Or do you specifically want to cut some of it off at smaller widths?

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! I know how to make it responsive, but I don't need it this time. I would like to keep its aspect ratio and original size, but hide horizontal part when it is wider than the container.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to simply cut some of the image off at smaller widths, you can set an **[`overflow: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)** on the parent, along with specifying both a **[`height`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)** and **[`width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/width)** for the parent:

```css
.image-container {
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.image-container > img {
  width: 800px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/800/400">
</div>
```

However, I'd suggest **scaling** the image (maintaining its aspect ratio) so that it can be entirely contained within the container / viewport. This can be achieved by setting a `width` of `100%` on the image, and not specifying a height:

```css
.image-container {
  max-width: 300px;
}

.image-container > img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/800/400">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. This code works. Has to specify the size for its container. I only do the clip for a small range of width, and make the image responsive when the width becomes even smaller and re-arrange the layout.

Answer (score 2):

```
.image-container {
overflow:hidden;
height: 350px;
width: 450px;
display:block;
}
img {
height: 400px;
width: 800px;
}

<div class="image-container">
<img src="https://placekitten.com/g/800/400">
</div>
```

Try this code use `overflow:hidden` on the container

Comment: i think the container also needs a size if it dosent already have one.

Comment: Try it again @curious1

Comment: Yes. Have to specify the size for the container. Upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to specify `width: 100%` simplifies right-sizing in many situations.